# Trying to make multicolumns of Young tableaux

Tags: tables, align, diagrams, tabularx, multicol

I am trying to make something like this picture. However, I was using \begin{multicols} and it doesn't work really well. Anyone can help me?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: There are several packages for Young tableaux (young, youngtab, ytableau), which of those are you using?

Comment: how about [ytableau](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau) package?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of packages for Young tableaux and you could, for instance, arrange them in a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[centertableaux]{ytableau}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{4}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
$\sigma_1=4$ & $P_1=\begin{ytableau} 4\\ \end{ytableau}$ & 
$Q_1=\begin{ytableau} 4\\ \end{ytableau}$\\
$\sigma_2=2$ & $P_2=\begin{ytableau} 2\\ 4\\ \end{ytableau}$ & 
$Q_2=\begin{ytableau} 1\\ 2\\\end{ytableau}$\\
$\sigma_3=6$ & $P_3=\begin{ytableau} 2 & 6\\ 4\\ \end{ytableau}$ & 
$Q_3=\begin{ytableau} 1 & 3\\ 2\\\end{ytableau}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The rest is repetition.